# Show Users who have a related entry

Tags: templating

I'm looking to show the users that have an entry relating to the `currentUser`, it is currently working but is obviously showing duplicates e.g. `admin, admin` as admin has 2x posts associated. Is there a better way of doing this and removing the duplicates? I just can't think of it.

```
{% set submissions = craft.entries.section('submissions').relatedTo({
  targetElement: currentUser,
  field: 'submissionBrand',
}) %}

{% for entry in submissions %}
    <li>{{ entry.author.username }}
{%  endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changed this to be :

```
{% set userBrands = craft.entries.section('brands').relatedTo(currentUser) %}
{% set fans = craft.users.relatedTo(userBrands) %}

{% for user in fans %}
    <li>{{ user.username }}
{%  endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```